# Gulp isn't compiling my sass when a file is changed

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using Gulp to compile my SCSS into CSS. When I initiate the Gulp command it will compile everything fine, but when I make a change to one of my SCSS files Gulp does nothing. So obviously its an issue with my Watch right?

I cant for the life of me figure out whats up, I've been searching for hours.

Here is what my Gulpfile.js and Folders look like.

```
// Include gulp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss' ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Folder structure:

```
gulpfile.js

    |
    |_ [scss folder]
        app.scss (this has all my imports)

        |
        |_ [pages folder]
                _thing.scss
                _thingtwo.scss

        |_ [general folder]
                _general.scss
                _generaltwo.scss

        |_ [widgets folder]
                _widget.scss
                _widgettwo.scss

       [css folder]
```

I believe my Gulp watch is looking inside of my scss folder for any changes to any scss in any folder. I tried moving my partials into the scss folder but still it doesn't compile when I save.

Comment: maybe `'scss/**.scss'?`

Comment: @sobolevn no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob string you have there are only looking one folder deep. If you want to watch all files in the scss directory and all its sub-directories, change the glob statements to `scss/**/*.scss` in the watch task.

Comment: Also, if you want to compile sheets in those sub-directories, you'll want to change the glob string in the sass task as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this still doesn't seem to work. I tried this: 'scss/**/*.scss' in both places and together  neither triggers gulp to compile when I saved a file.

Comment: This may be an obvious statement, but there's a comma missing in your watch statement: `gulp.watch('scss/*.scss' ['sass']);` should be `gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);` Does that fix it?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!  It seems I needed to add that coma and do what you originally recommended with the /**/*.scss